# For $\mathscr{A} \subseteq 2^E$, does $\{ B: B=E\setminus A, \text{ for some } A \in \mathscr{A} \}$ have a name?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, reference-request, terminology, definition

> **Question:** For a family of sets $\mathscr{A} \subseteq 2^E$, is there a term for $\{ B: B=A^c = E\setminus A, A \in \mathscr{A} \}$?
>
> I.e. is there a term for the family of all complements of sets in another family?

(If it matters, we can assume that the ground set $E$ is finite.)

Ideally a pointer to a reference using the suggested term would be appreciated, but isn't necessary.

**Attempt:** If $E$ is the ground set of a matroid, and $\mathscr{A}$ is the family of bases of that matroid, then the aforementioned family of sets, $\{B : B = E \setminus A = A^c, \text{ for some }A \in \mathscr{A} \}$ is exactly the family of bases of the dual matroid.

So perhaps one could, in general, call such families the **dual family of sets?**

Another thing I considered was to just call this family of sets $\mathscr{A}^c$, but then I realized that this is ambiguous and would lead to a lot of confusion. Specifically, one can also define $$opp(\mathscr{A}):= \{B \subseteq E: B \not\in \mathscr{A} \} $$ (I have seen this definition before in the literature, why I'm not also asking if it has a name too).

But then, w.r.t. $2^E$, $opp(\mathscr{A})$ is just the set complement of $\mathscr{A}$. So if one said "the complement of $\mathscr{A}$", suddenly one would have the ambiguity of whether (i) the family of sets which are complements of the sets in $\mathscr{A}$ (w.r.t. the ground set $E$), or (ii) the complement of $\mathscr{A}$ w.r.t. $2^E$, i.e. $opp(\mathscr{A})$, is meant.

Comment: I don't know a general term, but if the original family was a filter, this would be the cofilter, and if it were an ideal then it would be a coideal. In particular, the cocofilter is the filter.

Answer (score 1):

It makes sense to call it, as you suggest, the *dual family of sets*, although the term *dual* is overloaded in mathematics. Indeed, if you can consider $\mathscr{A}$ as a partially ordered set (with respect to inclusion), then your set is exactly the [dual partially ordered set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duality_(order_theory)).